# Is it on topic to ask about how implementations of a certain algorithm deal with certain problems?

Tags: discussion, support, on-topic, questions

For instance, would the following question be on-topic?

> In the context of training a decision tree, let $Y$ be the dependent
> variable and $X_1, \dots X_d$ the independent variables.
>
> In a typical implementation of a decision tree, the conditions used to
> split the dependent variable only involve a single dependent variable
> (e.g. $X_2 > t_{X_2}$). However, some implementations use conditions
> (called *oblique*) that involve more than a single feature (e.g. $X_1+ X_2 > t_{f(X_1, X_2)}$).
>
> In general, an oblique condition can be written as:
>
> $$  \sum_{j=0}^{k} w_iX_j \space < \space  \mu_{X_1, \dots, X_n} $$
>
> Since the number of features appearing in the condition $k$ and the
> weights of those features $w_i$ and the features themselves and the
> right member of the inequality can all change, this means that there
> is a very large number of possible conditions to split on, each
> having an associated measure of impurity that has to be calculated. How do the
> implementations of oblique decision trees go about addressing this
> issue?

Comment: It strikes me that there may be more than one implementation of this, & they may address this issue in different ways (I don't know that, it's just possible).  As a result, this question has a potential ambiguity that people might say requires clarification.  Other than that, I don't see any reason this Q would be objectionable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For all practical purposes, as gung - Reinstate Monica [noted](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6530/is-it-on-topic-to-ask-about-how-implementations-of-a-certain-algorithm-deal-with#comment22247_6530), these sort of queries can be positively entertained by the community. I am not seeing any reason it could be closed as off-topic.

But that might not deter one to potentially vtc the question for it being too broad/or needing more focus. I would be more specific with my query along with proper citation of sources. After that I would be having no qualms with it.